# Asp.Net Core 2.0 - Retrieve Image Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create a restful service that exposes some data, everything was just fine until I realize is a pain to expose images full URL from the server. Maybe it's just me but I am finding it very complicated.

Just to be in context, I am using Entity Framework to read from my Database, here is the table I am working with:

[image]

As you can see, there is a field named "ImagePath", bad name guys, it should be "ImageName", whatever, that column is saving the exact file name of the image that represents that Champion object, all the images are currently located inside the wwwroot project folder, just like this:

[image]

All the Business Logic is not at the controller, is at a Service folder/layer in a regular class (Maybe this is not relevant,  but I just wanted to clarify I am not working inside any controller):

[image]

And this is the method where I expect the magic to happen:

```
public async Task<IList<Champion>> GetChampions()
{
   List<Champion> champions = await _context.Champion
   .Include(x => x.PrimaryClass)
   .Include(x => x.SecondaryClass)
   .Include(x => x.ChampionUserRate)
   .ToListAsync();

   //BEFORE RETURNING THE CHAMPION TO THE CONTROLLER, I WILL NEED TO CONCATENATE MY CURRENT SERVER URL AND THE PATH TO THE IMAGE PLUS THE IMAGE NAME FILE WHICH IS ALREADY IN THE DATABASE AND ALREADY MATCHES THE IMAGES FOLDER

   string serverPathToChampionsFolder = null; //Example: http://localhost:57435/wwwroot/Champions

   foreach (var champion in champions)
   {
       champion.ImagePath = serverPathToChampionsFolder + champion.ImagePath;
   }

return champions;
}
```

Just to be clear here, the key line here is:

```
 string serverPathToChampionsFolder = null; //Example: http://localhost:57435/wwwroot/Champions
```

I need to somehow get the current URL just like in the example to add it to every single champion so it can be used by the client side inside an image tag.

If it is not possible to do it by the approach I am trying to implement I will accept any other suggestion, the point here is to expose the Image URL, does not matter how.

Comment: A simple approach would be to store the URL in appsettings.json, and inject settings object into the constructor of your service. What do you think?

Comment: @Brad to continue on that, use ```Url.Content($"~/Champions/{filename}");``` to make it work if the application isn't on the root path.

Comment: Where is this service class being called from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, you need to use `IHostingEnvironment` and inject it in your service constructor. Then create a string variable with the name of your folder inside the wwwroot let's say `"Champions"`

Here's the example code:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv;

private const string ChampionsImageFolder = "Champions";

public ChampionsService(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv){
    this.hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
}

// Suppose this method is responsible for fetching image path
public string GetImage(){
    var path = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, ChampionsImageFolder);

    return path;
}
```

What `IHostingEnvironment` interface does is "Provides information about the hosting environment an application is running in."

If you want to get files inside a given path, this will give you a hint.

```
var directoryFiles = Directory.GetFiles("wwwroot/Champions");

foreach (var item in directoryFiles)
{
    // do something here
}
```

If you want to create path link from those wwwroot folder, you need register in your startup the `UseDirectoryBrowser`

Inside your Startup.cs file, Find the `Configure` method insert this code snippet

These code snippets will expose files inside the `Champions` directory and create a new route on your website which is `ChampionImages` derived from folder `Champions` in your `wwwroot`

```
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "Champions")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/ChampionImages")
});
```

Then you can now use something like this `localhost:8080/ChampionImages` where you can see each file stored inside the Champions folder of your wwwroot. What you can do to create a URL of that image is something like this.

```
var imageUrl = $"/ChampionImages/{exactFileName}"; // this will create a string link.
```

I hope this simple code snippets give you help or idea :)

Comment: Won't this give the full OS path to the file?  You don't want to put that in an image tag.  I believe the OP wants the URL.

Comment: this will give the whole path including the OS path of course

Comment: What IHostingEnvironment does is "Provides information about the hosting environment an application is running in."

Comment: This code will give him hint what to do next. Once, he gets the full path of the folder, then he can now find what file he's actually looking depending on his needs.

Comment: @Brad I added another hint

Comment: OP code shows example paths as URL and states he needs the URL to be used in an image tag.

Comment: I see. well he needs to register the static files and directory browser in his startup @Brad

Comment: I updated and added some code snippet in my answer @Brad

Comment: If we assume that the OP already has `app.UseStaticFiles()` then his `wwwroot/Champions` folder is already exposed so what you've added is completely unnecessary.  How does it help him get the URL prefix into his image URL property?

Comment: Well, since the `wwwroot/Champions` is rewritten as the re-route  as `ChampionImages`, then can now create a url link image with that.

Comment: Let me remove the `UseStaticFiles` (to avoid confusion) what he actually needs is the `UseDirectoryBrowser` @Brad

Comment: I have a question my friend, i did what you said, when i try "http://localhost:54190/ChampionImages" i saw a list with all the files inside yeah?, but if a click on one of them or if i write manually to url to it like this: "http://localhost:54190/ChampionImages/aatrox.png" i get a HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked only until the folder structure, I can see until the folder, but when I take file it says 404. can you help on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Enable directory browsing
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/images")
            });
         
            app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/images")
            });
```

The above answer is correct, but still could not load the image url, so couple of lines need to add in startup.cs file, i am posting that here